# Disable scrolling of a button in a scrollable layout in android

Tags: android, scroll, appbar

I have a coordinator layout with a FrameLayout in it.
I set  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" for this framelayout.

but i want to have a button in this fragment that is fixed and i don't want that this button have scroll .
how should i do this??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="end">


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar in order to apply scrolling effects. -->
    <!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <!-- Toolbar is the actual app bar with text and the action items -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            layout="@layout/custom_action_bar" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/but_nav_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
   
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_layout" />

<include layout="@layout/navigation_bar" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is code of myFragment

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shopsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        text="button"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned where you want a button to be fixed.
Adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will fixed the button at the bottom of the screen.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="button" />
```

Comment: i set    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" but when scroll recycle view,the button scroll a little...i don't understand why this happen and how can fix it.